# Converting from Washington State Plane Coordinates to Web Mercator?

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, openlayers, convert

I received coordinate data in Washington State Plane: EPSG:14602. I need to convert this to EPSG: 3857, aka Web Mercator.

I'm using Javascript. Here's what I've tried so far:

Using OpenLayers: `ol.proj.transform`. This doesn't work since it does not contain the definition for EPSG: 14602.

To add definition, I used `ol.proj4js`. Issue with that is that it also needs a definition to begin with.

Looking for that definition, I found this website: https://epsg.io/14602 If you try https://epsg.io/14602.js, you get an empty definition. But if you try https://epsg.io/3857.js, you get a full proper definition.

How/where do I get the definition as formatted in https://epsg.io/3857.js?

Do you know of any tools that convert or might be close?

Perhaps, guide me towards the math and I can do it manually?

Comment: Is it equivalent to EPSG:32049?  The parameters in the WKT look similar.to those in that XML

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE GIS!  Are you a fellow Washingtonian?

I suspect that your problem is linked to the data you received.  There are a couple of things to consider:

1. Washington state is divided into two [State Plane Coordinate System](https://www.gislounge.com/state-plane-coordinate-system/) zones: North and South (I'd display an image of that dividing line for you, but I can't find it at the moment). Anyway, that [official](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=58.20&full=true) line zigzags horizontally across the state, roughly through the middle.  EPSG:2926 covers the north zone, while EPSG:2927 covers the south zone.  When dealing with spatial data covering the *entire* state, the parameters found within [EPSG:2927](http://epsg.io/2927) are used by convention, with statewide features projected into EPSG:2927.
2. So what should we make of EPSG:14602?  As you have found, there is no such thing.  However, there is a clue: remove the 1 and you're left with the number 4602, which happens to be the [FIPS code for Washington State Plane Coordinate system, South Zone](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/FGCS/BlueBook/pdf/Annex_B.pdf), which is our old friend EPSG:2927!  ESRI software adds to the confusion by referring to EPSG:2927 as *NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Washington_South_FIPS_4602_Feet*.  Notice the 4602?

So, I suspect that your data is most likely EPSG:2927, and that 4602 somehow got incorrectly mixed up into 14602.  Perhaps you could confirm by 1) contacting your data supplier, or 2) by reviewing the layer's metadata, if it exists, or 3) by editing your original SE post and displaying a screenshot of the layer's properties from the the GIS software you are using, so that folks here could also look at it.